# Can't understand why SqlConnection is returning System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

This is baffling me.  I have this line of code that is causing the problem

```
string prodID = DBTools.getProdID(args[0]).ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

When I run this in my program I eventually get an error.

```
public static SqlCommand getProdID(string server)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT Password FROM UTrainID";
        SqlCommand cmd = createCmd(server, "AACSMapping", sql);
        cmd.Connection.Open(); // this generates the System.NullReferenceException
        return cmd;
    }
```

The thing that is baffling me about this is that I have a UnitTest that tests this that works perfectly.

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void getProdIDTest()
    {
        string ID = UTrain.DBTools.getProdID("PN1173312").ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        Assert.IsTrue(ID.Equals("XXXXXXXXX"));
    }
```

When I run this console application I've checked that the Args[] values are right i.e. it's the same value that I have in the UnitTest.  The other things that is bothersome about this is that when I try to debug it by stepping through the code it works fine!  That tells me that it's a timing problems of some type but that's beyond me.  Here is the code that creates the actual connection.

```
public static SqlConnection createConnection(string server, string initcat)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder strBuild = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            strBuild.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            strBuild.InitialCatalog = initcat;
            strBuild.DataSource = server;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strBuild.ConnectionString);
            return conn;
        } // end try
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            writeErrorMessage(e, "Could not create connection.");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I don't know that it makes any difference but the reason I break the code up like this is I'm connecting to a number of different databases so it makes it easier to do it like this I feel.

Comment: Well the fact that if `createConnection` has a problem, it logs the error but then returns null (rather than just letting the exception propagate) doesn't help. Have you debugged into this? Is an error message written out? As an aside, it would be a good idea to follow .NET naming conventions...

Comment: I think we need to see the definition of the method `createCmd` to answer this.

Comment: Best guess is you didn't set the `Connection` on the `SqlCommand` returned by the `createCmd` method.

Comment: Jon Skeet, I see what you're talking about -- now.  Yes that was a dumb way to handle the exception.  Where are the .NET naming conventions?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx I can't speak for @jonskeet but my guess would be he is referring to your use of camel case for your method names over pascal case.

Comment: Yeah after doing a search on MSDN I found that.  Thanks for the clarification though GarethD

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.  I finally found the problem.  It was throwing a error that was being written to the error log file.  It was a "Type initializer for SqlConnection threw an exception"  When I searched for that error message most concerns were with the app.config file.  I checked that and it was not formatted correctly.  There was an extra >.  I can see why the unit test might have worked when running unit tests I guess they wouldn't load the app.config file, but I still don't understand why stepping through with the debugger would work correctly?

Comment: You should never catch an exception like that and then return null, it just sets you up for a null reference exception. You should let the exception propagate up to the UI layer and display the problem there, or if it's a service application then halt execution and notify developers.